# Getting this error "Uncaught Type Error: a is not iterable" while using reduce

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which roughly look like this:

```
var arr = [{id: 1, name:"Sam", loc: "A"}, {id: 2, name:"Sam", loc: "A"}, {id: 3, name:"fam",loc: "C"}];
```

From this I want to get another array like this (an array of objects containing name and location of 'Sam' ):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "loc": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "loc": "A"
  }
]

var res = arr.reduce((a, {name, loc})=>{
   name === "Sam" ? [...a, {name, loc}] : a ;
}, []);
```

But I'm getting an error:

Uncaught Type-error: a is not iterable

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `filter` would be a dramatically better choice than `reduce` there. `const res = arr.filter(({name}) => name === "Sam");` Unless you're doing FP (functional programming) and passing a pre-existing function into `reduce`, there are almost always better alternatives than `reduce`, usually a simple loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder may be they want the array of objects without 'id'?

Comment: @ABGR - The data show has only the properties being used. If there were more and they were excerpting them, I'd use a loop first or `filter`+`map`. Like [some](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) [others](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224), my view is that `reduce` is almost never the right tool.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder haha the threads are hilarious. But can `reduce` perform better than `filter+map`, say, in this case because of two loops in the later? Also, I don't have a data to prove, but I have observed the answers written with `reduce` tend to get higher upvotes here on SO. :p

Comment: @ABGR - One pass can be better than two, yes, which is why I'd use a simple loop if I were dealing with hundreds of thousands of array elements. Voting patterns are weird. :-) People do tend to upvote things that seem cool. But being cool isn't what development is about (to me). Being clear is more important (to me). :-)

Comment: One argument people generally use against `for..loop` is that it  would require mutating variables. For e.g https://stackoverflow.com/a/62058988/4650975 this got downvoted maybe because I used a `forEach` instead of `reduce` and a comment was left regarding the mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing `return` in the callback of your `reduce`. Try this:

```js
var arr = [{id: 1, name:"Sam", loc: "A"}, {id: 2, name:"Sam", loc: "A"}, {id: 3, name:"fam",loc: "C"}];

var res = arr.reduce((a, {name, loc})=>{
   return name === "Sam" ? [...a, {name, loc}] : a ;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is an *often* repeated duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yup okay